# Issues with ApexChart.js

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I have 3 issues Please refer to this [codepen](https://codepen.io/haha11/pen/MWKrVqq) and this picture [image]

1. I try to disable mouse-hover behavior for donut chart by using config, following this [#issue322](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/322) but it's not working. Hover still working whenever mouse on top of something
2. How to make labels at the center to fit in white space only? not overlapping with the graph? I try to use `\n` and `<br>` but still can't make it as 2 lines. `\n` only turn into white space.
3. How to limit data label percentage to no decimal?
4. Is it possible to put datalabel on the right of its segment?

```html
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>

  <script>
    var options = {
      series: [44, 55, 41, 17, 15],
      chart: {
        type: "donut",
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function (val, opts) {
          return opts.w.config.series[opts.seriesIndex] + " : " + val;
        },
      },

      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          startAngle: 0,
          expandOnClick: true,
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
          customScale: 1,
          dataLabels: {
            offset: 0,
            minAngleToShowLabel: 10,
          },
          donut: {
            size: "65%",
            background: "transparent",
            labels: {
              show: true,
              name: {
                show: true,
                fontSize: "22px",
                fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                fontWeight: 600,
                color: undefined,
                offsetY: -10,
                formatter: function (val) {
                  return val;
                },
              },
              value: {
                show: true,
                fontSize: "16px",
                fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                fontWeight: 400,
                color: undefined,
                offsetY: 16,
                formatter: function (val) {
                  return val;
                },
              },
              total: {
                show: true,
                showAlways: false,
                label: "Total Accumulated Mandate",
                fontSize: "22px",
                fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                fontWeight: 600,
                color: "#373d3f",
                formatter: function (w) {
                  return w.globals.seriesTotals.reduce((a, b) => {
                    return a + b;
                  }, 0);
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      legend: {
        show: false,
      },
      // responsive: [{
      //     enabled: false,
      //   breakpoint: 980,
      //   options: {
      //     chart: {
      //       width: 500
      //     },
      //     legend: {
      //      show: false
      //     }
      //   }
      // }]
      states: {
        hover: {
          filter: {
            type: "none",
          },
        },
      },
    };

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
    chart.render();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You've included several, unrelated questions, in this one question. Take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider narrowing the focus. This might make it easier for people to help out.

Answer (score 0):

For no 3, just simply use `parseInt(val)`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved three issues other than first one: Try this code

```
 var options = {
      series: [44, 55, 41, 17, 15],
      chart: {
        type: "donut",
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function (val, opts) {
          /* Format labels here */
          return opts.w.config.series[opts.seriesIndex];
        },
      },

      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          startAngle: 0,
          expandOnClick: true,
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
          customScale: 1,
          dataLabels: {
            offset: 0,
            minAngleToShowLabel: 10,
          },
          donut: {
            size: "65%",
            background: "transparent",
            labels: {
              show: true,
              name: {
                show: true,
                fontSize: "16px",
                fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                
                color: undefined,
                offsetY: 0,
                formatter: function (val) {
                  return val;
                },
              },
              value: {
                show: true,
                fontSize: "16px",
                fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                fontWeight: 400,
                color: undefined,
                offsetY: 16,
                formatter: function (val) {
                  return val
                },
              },
              total: {
                show: true,
                showAlways: false,
                label: "Total Accumulated Mandate",
                /* Set fontsize here and accordingly for responsiveness */
                fontSize: "16px",
                fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                fontWeight: 600,
                color: "#373d3f",
                formatter: function (w) {
                  return w.globals.seriesTotals.reduce((a, b) => {
                    return a + b;
                  }, 0);
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      legend: {
        show: true
      },
      // responsive: [{
      //     enabled: false,
      //   breakpoint: 980,
      //   options: {
      //     chart: {
      //       width: 500
      //     },
      //     legend: {
      //      show: false
      //     }
      //   }
      // }]
      states: {
        hover: {
          filter: {
            type: "none",
          },
        },
      },
    };
```